# dotted line is not coming till the end in uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a dotted line, I have tried with the code below:

```
 private func createDottedView(for view:UIView) {
        let width: CGFloat = 1
        let color: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let caShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        caShapeLayer.strokeColor = color
        caShapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        caShapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [9,3]
        let cgPath = CGMutablePath()
        let cgPoint = [CGPoint(x: view.layer.bounds.minX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: view.layer.bounds.maxX, y: 0)]
        cgPath.addLines(between: cgPoint)
        caShapeLayer.path = cgPath
        view.layer.addSublayer(caShapeLayer)
    }
```

But this is not coming till end, how can i get this dotted line till end?

[image: this is what i am getting]

Comment: Keep in mind that a layer's frame is not automatically updated by the system when the view frame changes. You need to update its frame yourself. A possible reason is that you were adding the dotted line when the view is being laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an image misted of making a uiview a dotted line because of the  CAShapeLayer()
It can cause this type of problem. So you can just download a similar image and place the image view inside the uiview and use the image to make it scale to fill it should work.

Or if you want to do it with coding only you can change your code with the given live of code the rest of the code will work fine.

```
let cgPoint =  [CGPoint(x: view.layer.bounds.minX, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 
view.layer.bounds.maxX+40, y: 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add `trailing` and `leading` constraints on the UIView as shown  below in the `storyboard`.

[Added constrainsts to the lineView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAziU.png)

[Output of dotted UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiJXq.png)

Comment: yes added leading and trailing constraints, you can see clearly in image yellow background, but still it is not coming till end

Comment: Try to add the UIView once again after deleting it and add the constraints on it. Output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmyXB.png